# React Native change status bar text color in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar, textcolor

I'm developing an app using React Native, I've been asked to set the text color of the status bar in white.

I used the StatusBar component with the property barStyle="light-content" and it works pretty well on Android but not on iOS, the text color is still black.

I did some research about it but I couldn't find anything helpful. I even tried to select the Light Status bar style on XCode [like the following picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpPPi.png) but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try this it may helps you : https://github.com/RNRF/react-native-router-flux/issues/2882

Comment: @Kuldeep I've already checked that link before writting this post, it didn't really help me, I'm trying a lot of stuff at the moment but I'm still stuck

Comment: @Fabrizio you should write your solution as an answer and accept it so that others coming to this questions can easily see the solution (feels weird to answer your own question but it's common practice on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @MateiRadu noted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem !

The issue came from a React Native library called React Native Navbar, it was taking control of the status bar as well, I had to setup the 'light-content' property in that component.

Answer (score 22):

I solved the problem!
I use this code in Index page and set the text color to white:

```js
<StatusBar  barStyle="light-content" translucent={true} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your AppDelegate file.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Objective c

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

and in your info.plist file set **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance** to **NO**

Comment: I tried your code but as I'm developing in React Native, the AppDelegate file is written in Objective C, I tried to find the similar line of code written in Objective C but I'm really struggling with it, so far it's not working

Comment: In Objective C setStatusBarStyle is deprecated, I still tried that line of code but the text color of the status bar is still black, I do think that React Native is taking over that code, sadly I don't know what to do about it.

I also forgot to mention in my first post that there is only one view where the text color is white, once I go to to another view it switches to black and when I go back to the "white text color view" it's not white anymore but black, it's really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

<StatusBar backgroundColor={"white"} barStyle="dark-content" />